# Why won't Mvc 4 application pick up email column added to UserProfile table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

As the question suggests I added an email column to the UserProfile table.
(As I need a valid email address for each user)
However when I try to access this in a "Lost Password" feature, I get the following error.

```
 {"The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent1,Column name = UserEmail ]"}
```

The code block in the my LostPassword Action in my Account controller.

```
  // can't access UserProfile table with Email value
                var foundUserName = (from u in db.UserProfiles
                                     where u.UserEmail == model.Email
                                     select u.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I get application to recognise the email column to check against users input.
Please note this is an MVC 4 application built with VS 2010 and using Simple Membership.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you regenerate the database from your model when adding the column? either your database or edmx model does not contain this column

Comment: when I view the database in SQL Server Management Studio, the column is present and when viewing through Server Explorer in Visual Studio. I don't see the edmx model (it's usually in the App_Data folder, yes?) this folder does contian ASPnetdb.MDF and a DefaultConnection.sdf

Comment: Everything else surrounding the database is working, but should the database name in Accounts model match that in SQL studio .... as opposed to public UserContext() : base ("DefaultConnection") ??